# ASP.NET ModelBinding Complex Objects / Nested ListViews

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I want to use asp.net webforms model binding and nest a listview in a listview.  Is this possible?

Currently I have set DataKeyNames on the parent and use the [Control] attribute in the SelectMethod and the method gets called for every row int the parent but the parameter is null.

Any help is appriciated.

```
<asp:ListView ID="Topics" runat="server"
    ItemType="Topic"
    SelectMethod="Topics_GetData"
    DataKeyNames="ID" >
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <div class="notice">
                    There are no Questions.
                </div>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div><%# Item.TopicName %></div>

        <asp:ListView ID="QuestionSetListView" runat="server"
            ItemType="Question"
            SelectMethod="QuestionListView_GetData"
                 DataKeyNames="ID">
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <div class="notice">
                        There are no Questions.
                    </div>
                </EmptyDataTemplate> ...
```

The select method :

```
QuestionListView_GetData([Control("Topics")] int? ID)
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great to see someone doing cool things with Web Forms model binding.
You can definitely do it, you just need to use a HiddenField to hold your ID,

```
<div><%# Item.TopicName %></div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="TopicID" runat="server" Value="<%# Item.ID %>" />
<asp:ListView ID="QuestionSetListView" runat="server"
```

And then refer to the TopicID in your Control Attribute

```
QuestionListView_GetData([Control("TopicID")] int? ID)
```

Comment: Nice!!! now I need to figure out how do this with formview to insert these objects in the db.

Comment: Glad you liked it, a FormView works pretty much the same. I've done some examples with a FormView inside a ListView if you're interested? Have a look at my 'Navigation Identity for VS 2013.zip' sample available at https://navigation.codeplex.com/documentation